# How to know when the user has started an Apple Watch app?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I would like to know when the user starts my Apple Watch app (started from menu or from complication). [WKInterfaceController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller)'s documentation states that the [didAppear](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1628221-didappear) method is called when the interface controller content is on screen.

In my [simple example project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1I0Nb9ECaydm5RzuZM-6TdV224KItirap) I'm logging all calls to the `didAppear` method, and I see that it gets called also when the app is not visible on screen.

```
override func didAppear() {
   super.didAppear()
   log("didAppear") // Triggered when app not visible
}
```

My guess is that this has to do with snapshot refreshing, but is there any way to know when the user (not the system) has started my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `applicationDidBecomeActive` for this.

[From Apple Developer Documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1628185-applicationdidbecomeactive)

> WatchKit calls this method to let you know that your app transitioned from the inactive to the active state. Use this method to start any tasks that were paused or not yet started while the app was inactive.

Comment: In only get one single `applicationDidFinishLaunching` call on multiple app startups (the app lives in the background thus only one launch). Updated sample project code.

Comment: @stoffen In that case, you are looking for a different method. Updated my answer.